# setValue onComplete not called from Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My code on `onCompleteListener` works successfully when registering process but nothing happen when `setValue` is called. I have read some answers in here stackoverflow,

> [OnCompleteListener is not called for .setValue in RealtimeDatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513101/oncompletelistener-is-not-called-for-setvalue-in-realtimedatabase)
>
> [setValue onComplete not called from Firebase on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072547/setvalue-oncomplete-not-called-from-firebase-on-android?rq=1)

but I am having a hard time reading their code.

This is successful `onCompleteListener` code when registering process

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
             if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                sendToMainAcitivy();

             } else {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
     }
});
```

and this is my unsuccessful code, nothing happens with this code

```
 reference
          .child("someChild")
          .setValue(someValue)
          .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                       if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                           sendToMainActivity();

                       } else {
                         Toast.makeText(UserName.this, "try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }
                }
         });
```

Comment: are you getting the write to your database with .setValue(someValue) ? maybe the problem is at your reference

Comment: What do you mean by "Nothing happens with this code"?

Comment: i am very sure there is no problem on someValue the probelem only on `onComplete` @GastónSaillén

Comment: nothing happen, no reaction at all, no error and no life@ChrisNeve

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint? is your onComplete() method called? What does sendToMainActivity() do?

Comment: sendToMain calls Intent, go to class MainActivity.class@ChrisNeve