# Firebase .removeValue() adds deleted element automatically

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm new to firebase and i have a problem with the method .removeValue(), everytime that method is executed the addOnCompleteListener does not throw any exceptions and execute the .removeValue() method correctly by removing the element but the element keeps adding by itself after the deletion,

I'm trying to do a friend's list where i check the condition if there is a friend request or is the 2 users are actually friends, So i wrote this code on the onStart method to assign the stats variable a value according to these conditions:

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(profileUid.equals(userId)){
        sendAccept.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else {

        friendDatabaseReference.child(userId).child(profileUid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    String status = dataSnapshot.child("Status").getValue().toString();


                    if (status.equals("recieved")) {
                        sendAccept.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        sendAccept.setText("Accept Request");
                        cancelRequest.setText("Cancel friend Request");
                        cancelRequest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        stats = "recieved";

                    } else if (status.equals("sent")) {
                        stats = "sent";
                        sendAccept.setText("Cancel Friend Request");
                    }
                } else {
                    friendDatabaseReference1.child(userId).child(profileUid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                stats = "friends";
                                sendAccept.setText("UnFriend");
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Everything runs well there and the values are assigned correctly. After that depending of the value of stats these conditions can happen(These sendAccept.setOnClickistener()) is on the onCreate() method:

```
        sendAccept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (stats.equals("none")) {
                friendDatabaseReference.child(userId).child(profileUid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                            friendDatabaseReference.child(userId).child(profileUid).child("Status").setValue("sent").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        friendDatabaseReference.child(profileUid).child(userId).child("Status").setValue("recieved").addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    stats = "sent";
                                                    sendAccept.setText("Cancel Friend Request");
                                                }

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }

                                }

                            });

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {


                    }
                });
            }else if(stats.equals("recieved")){
                friendDatabaseReference1.child(userId).child(profileUid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        friendDatabaseReference1.child(userId).child(profileUid).child("friends").setValue("yes")
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                            friendDatabaseReference1.child(profileUid).child(userId).child("friends").setValue("yes")
                                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                                                stats = "friends";
                                                                sendAccept.setText("Unfriend");
                                                                cancelRequest.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                                                friendDatabaseReference.child(userId).child(profileUid).removeValue()
                                                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                            @Override
                                                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                                    friendDatabaseReference.child(profileUid).child(userId)
                                                                                            .removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(
                                                                                            new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                                                                @Override
                                                                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                                                                                }
                                                                                            });

                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        });
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });



            }else if(stats.equals("sent")){
                friendDatabaseReference.child(userId).child(profileUid).removeValue()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    friendDatabaseReference.child(profileUid).child(userId).removeValue()
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    stats = "none";
                                                    sendAccept.setText("Send Friend Request");
                                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Asi que prende", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                }

                            }
                        });

            }else{
                friendDatabaseReference1.child(userId).child(profileUid).removeValue()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    friendDatabaseReference1.child(profileUid).child(userId).removeValue()
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    sendAccept.setText("Send Friend Request");
                                                    stats = "none";
                                                }
                                            });
                                }

                            }
                        });

            }
        }

    });
```

These are my declared instances of FirebaseDatabase where i point out where the data will be or will be removed(these are also on the onCreate() method:

```
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
    friendDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("friend_req");
    friendDatabaseReference1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends");
```

The conditions don't throw any errors nor exceptions, and all the assigns are working well and finally the firebase deletes the record, but add it again after the deletion

Comment: You're not doing anything in `onComplete`. It'd be good to see what happens if you `throw task.getException()` in there.

Comment: W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.meetingroom.ProfileActivity$3$3$1.onComplete(ProfileActivity.java:237)                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                 that is thrown in the line where i put the task.getException() , also i don't know what do you mean that i am not doing anything in onComplete when the button text change when the task is successful

Comment: Can you implement `onComplete` as this user has done in their question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072547/setvalue-oncomplete-not-called-from-firebase-on-android and then include both the updated code and its log output in the question?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, it was that i added a ValueEventListener after the  condition stats.equals("none") runs, so i guess that the ValueEventListener within the if(stats.equals("none") block will execute  everytime the data change even though the condition stats.equals("none") wasn't true, I guess i'm right in that part